# CATiledLayer shows previous tiles

Tags: ios, swift, catiledlayer

When invalidating a view backed by a CATiledLayer, a previous tile remains "stuck" and isn't correctly invalidated.

This seems to happen when the view is invalidated (on the main thread), while at the same time, the tile render threads are still working on a previous version of the tile. Instead of caching the new version of the tile, the previous version is cached.

The view backed by CATiledLayer is a subview of a UIScrollView and is zoomable. The rendering of a tile can be expensive and can use the render thread for 10ms.

### Example

Example code that demonstrates this issue: https://github.com/Q42/CATiledLayerBug

1. In a CATiledLayer, start rendering all red tiles (this would take about 3 seconds to complete)
2. Each render step takes about 10ms
3. During rendering (after 800ms), invalidate the complete view:    `tiledView.setNeedsDisplay()`
4. Start rendering all gray tiles (this again takes about 3 seconds)
5. Two tiles (randomly?) remain red, instead of becoming gray.

See the `update` function here: https://github.com/Q42/CATiledLayerBug/blob/master/TiledLayerTest/ViewController.swift#L45

[image: screenshot]

### Workaround?

This seems to be a bug in the implementation of `CATiledLayer`. Since I can't fix that, does anyone know of a good workaround for this issue?

I've filed a radar for this: http://www.openradar.me/28648050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some further logging I've added to the example project, I think the problem is this:

The `CATiledLayer` has two render threads that draw each tile. If, during the execution of a `draw(_: CGRect)` call a `setNeedsDisplay` is called, the current execution of the `draw` call is finished and the result is cached. The cached value is based on the previous "data source" (just the tile color in this example), rather that the updated data source.

An Apple support engineer provided me with a workaround:

- Add an `updateID` field to the TiledView
- Add the start of a `draw(_: CGRect)` call save the current `updateID`
- When the "data source" changes, change the `updateID`
- Add the end of the `draw(_: CGRect)` call, compare the saved `updateID` with the current one.
- If the ids differ, schedule a new `setNeedsDisplay` call.

Extract:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
  let originalID = updateID

  // all actual (slow) drawing code here...

  if originalID != updateID {

    // dispatch a redraw request, but wait a little while first
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(17)) {
      self.layer.setNeedsDisplayIn(rect)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This workaround is not working for NSView, Did you find any other alternative?

Comment: I've been using this workaround for the past two years. It's still working fine on iOS.